# Slow data-processing and inefficient memory usage in .NET containers

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net, memory-management

I am writing a text classifier, and in order to do so, I need TF/IDF values per every word of my single text.

Then I need to use the cosine similarity:

$$similarity = cos(\theta) = \dfrac{A \cdot B}{\lVert A \lVert \lVert B \lVert} = \dfrac{\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\LARGE\Sigma}}A_i \times B_i}{\sqrt{ \overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\LARGE\Sigma}}(A_i)^2} \times \sqrt{\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\LARGE\Sigma}}(B_i)^2}}$$

This requires processing of a big data storage (all of the texts that already exists in my database). The problem is that my code is doing his job for about 2 hours (quite too long) and breaks giving me message that I have run out of memory. I think that the main method might be very, very unoptimised.

```
public static void CreateCategoryClasses()
{
    deserializeClasses = Deserialize();
    howManyClasses = deserializeClasses.Count;
    ewhClass = new EventWaitHandle[howManyClasses];

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        categoryClasses.Enqueue(new ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>());
        result.Enqueue(new ConcurrentDictionary<string, double>());
    }
    WaitCallback threadMethod = ParseCategories;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(howManyStudents, howManyClasses);

    for (var i = 0; i < howManyClasses; ++i)
    {
        ewhClass[i] = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadMethod, i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < howManyClasses; ++i)
    {
        ewhClass[i].WaitOne();
    }
    threadMethod = AddIDF;
    ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(howManyStudents, 5);

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ewhClass[i] = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(threadMethod, i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ewhClass[i].WaitOne();
    }

    List<List<SingleWords>> efekt = new List<List<SingleWords>>(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        foreach (var secondWord in categoryClasses.ToList()[i])
        {
            result[i].Add(new SingleWords(secondWord.Key, secondWord.Value));
        }
    }
    var xmls = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<List<SingleWords>>));
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(@"categoryClasses.xml"))
    {
        xmls.Serialize(sw, efekt);
    }
}

private static void AddIDF(object index)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread started with id:" + index + " and number: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    var i = index as int?;
    double sum;
    foreach (var word in categoryClasses.ElementAt(i.Value))
    {
        sum =
            deserializeClasses.Count(
                clas =>
                    clas.Bag.Where(x => clas.Category == ((Categories)i.Value).ToString())
                        .Contains(new Words(word.Key, 0, 0)));
        var temp = Convert.ToDouble(sum) /
                   Convert.ToDouble(
                       deserializeClasses.Count(x => x.Category == ((Categories)i.Value).ToString()));
        result.ElementAt(i.Value).AddOrUpdate(word.Key, temp, (s, d) => temp);
    }
    ewhClass[(i).Value].Set();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ended with id:" + index + " and number: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

Comment: "the main method seems very very unoptimized"... ***which main method?***

Comment: I've pasted only two methods, only one of them calls the second one so the 'main method' refers to CreateCategoryClasses

Comment: I see assignments to undeclared variables in a static method, and my spidey senses are off the charts. Shared static state, in a multi-threaded program no less: brace yourself for more memory leaks and heisenbugs and various other goodness.

Comment: I would eliminate the use of xml and LINQ both. It is not that they are always inefficient. It is that you may waste a lot of time trying to optimize them. You need to use a profiler, and the quickest use of that will be with simple code. Also, abuzittin gillifirca's remarks are very important!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit in response to OP comment above:**

`CreateCategoryClasses` may appear to be slow because of the `WaitOne` calls.  You're essentially waiting waiting on either `ParseCategories` or `AddIDF` to complete before moving on. It would help if you could also post the `ParseCategories` method as well.  Otherwise, you're just adding stuff to collections, which generally shouldn't perform too bad, except for some of my comments below.

**Original answer:**

Some of this is performance suggestions, some is just general advice...

1. If you have one, run this through a performance profiler. This can point you directly to the lines that are using the most CPU time very quickly. Personally, I use *ANTS* from *Red Gate*.  Another good one is *DotTrace* from *JetBrains*.
2. Why is `categoryClasses` a `ConcurrentQueue`?  As a general rule, a `Queue` is used for removing the items as you process them. If you just need to loop over a collection (possibly multiple times), a `List<T>` would be a better choice. This would also avoid the call to `ToList()` each time through your `secondWord` loop.  `ToList()` will iterate through the entire collection every time you call it (granted it's only 5 element, but still...). This may also apply to `result` as well, depending on where else it might be used.
3. You call `ElementAt()` every time through your `foreach` loop in `AddIDF`, even though `i` isn't changing.  If you must use a `ConcurrentQueue` for `categoryClasses`, then `ElementAt()` is \$O(i)\$.  If you can use a `List`, then it will be \$O(1)\$.  You could save the current `ConcurrentDictionary` before the loop to avoid the repetitive indexing.
4. String comparisons are slow compared to integers and enums (your `Where()` calls in `AddIDF`). If you changed `Category` to an enum or integer (or possibly add a second property for comparison purposes), that would improve the count performance.
5. You pass an `int` into your `AddIDF` method, not an `int?`, so you can just do a direct cast to an `int`.  This avoids the `.Value` property everywhere you access the index in `AddIDF`.
6. `sum` is already a `double`, so there's no need to call `Convert.ToDouble`. Because `sum` is a `double`, `temp` will be a `double`, even if the result of `Count` is an `int`.
7. What is this `5` I keep seeing?  Typically it's good to assign this to a `const` value for clarity.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Nice answer, feel free to meet the site regulars in [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) anytime!

Answer (score 4):

You're doing a lot of needless work in `AddIDF`:

- `((Categories)i.Value).ToString()` can be computed just once per function call.
- `new Words(word.Key, 0, 0)` can be computed just once per iteration.
- The denominator of `temp` can be lifted out of the loop.

The body of the expression `x => clas.Category == ((Categories)i.Value).ToString()` does not refer to `x`, so you're iterating through *every element* of the bag, which you don't need to do.

The call to `Contains` is on a sequence, not the collection `clas.Bag`, making it an \$O(n)\$ operation, while if `clas.Bag` is a `HashSet`, it would be \$O(1)\$.

Putting that together would look like this:

```
private static void AddIDF(object index)
{
    var i = (index as int?).Value;
    var category = ((Categories)i).ToString();
    var bags = deserializeClasses.Where(clas => clas.Category == category)
        .Select(clas => clas.Bag)
        .ToList();
    var denominator = Convert.ToDouble(bags.Count);

    foreach (var word in categoryClasses.ElementAt(i))
    {
        var key = word.Key;
        var target = new Words(key, 0, 0);
        var sum = bags.Count(bag => bag.Contains(target));
        var temp = sum / denominator;

        result.ElementAt(i)
            .AddOrUpdate(key, temp, (s, d) => temp);
    }

    ewhClass[i].Set();
}
```

I added some classes to make your function compile, and have put up a gist here: https://gist.github.com/mjolka/7f5b6055028285e2eb68. On my machine, for a Release build running under Mono 3.4.0, the timings for the different implementations of AddIDF are ~ **00:00:00.6** vs ~ **00:01:26.4**.

Other notes:

- Posting a minimal complete code sample would greatly help -- one that readers can drop into LINQPad or similar and run.
- Class names are usually singular, e.g. `SingleWord` instead of `SingleWords`, and `Category` instead of `Categories`.